# numba eager compilation? Whats the pattern?

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, vectorization, numba

I looked into eager compilation on numba's website and couldnt figure out, how to specify the types:

The example they use is this:

```
from numba import jit, int32

@jit(int32(int32, int32))
def f(x, y):
    # A somewhat trivial example
    return x + y

# source: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#eager-compilation
```

as you can see it gets 2 variables as input and returns one single variable. all of them should be int32.

One way to understand the decorator is that `@jit(int32(int32, int32))` could be understood as:

`@jit`(`type_of_returned_value`(`type_of_x`, `type_of_b`))

If that is right (Is that right?), then how do you specify it for multiple inputs and outputs?

Like this:

```
@nb.jit
def filter3(a,b):
    return a > b 

@nb.jit
def func3(list_of_arrays_A, list_of_arrays_B, list_of_arrays_C, list_of_arrays_D, 2d_numpy_array_of_objects):

    for i in range(len(list_of_arrays_A)): 

        for j in range(list_of_arrays_A[i].size):
            
            if filter3(list_of_arrays_A[i][j],list_of_arrays_B[i][j]):
                2d_numpy_array_of_objects[i][j] = 1

            elif filter3(list_of_arrays_B[i][j],list_of_arrays_A[i][j]):
                2d_numpy_array_of_objects[i][j] = 0

            elif filter3(list_of_arrays_C[i][j],list_of_arrays_D[i][j]): 
                2d_numpy_array_of_objects[i][j] = 0
            else:                       
                2d_numpy_array_of_objects[i][j] = 1 
'''

My intention: Since i need to speed up a function which is only called once, (but takes forever if **not** done with numba), I need to speed up its numba-compilation
```

Comment: Eager compilation isn't *faster* compilation. You're just doing it earlier, not faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can always use [`numba.typeof`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#numba.typeof) to interfere type of a variable. e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
N=10000
simple_list= [np.zeros(1) for x in range(N)]
nb.typeof(simple_list)
# reflected list(array(float64, 1d, C))
```

or:

```
from numba.typed import List
typed_list=List()
for _ in range(N):
    typed_list.append(np.zeros(1))
nb.typeof(typed_list)
# ListType[array(float64, 1d, C)]
```

So you can provide the signatures as follows to ahead-of-time compilation:

```
@nb.jit([nb.void(nb.typeof(typed_list)),
         nb.void(nb.typeof(simple_list))])
def fun(lst):
    pass
```

Noteworthy details:

- I'm compiling the function ahead of time in two different versions: one for numba's TypedList (`nb.void(nb.typeof(typed_list)`) and one for python's list (`nb.void(nb.typeof(simple_list))`).
- I don't use the signature strings , but the signatures themselves (for example described [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html)), because there exists no signature string for `TypedList` or reflected list if I understand it correctly (more info follows bellow).
- As the function `fun` doesn't return anything, the return type of the function is `void`, thus `nb.void(...)` in signatures.

However, the interesting thing is how much more overhead `simple_list`-version has:

```
%timeit fun(simple_list)  # 185 ms ± 4.23 ms 
%timeit fun(typed_list)   # 1.18 µs ± 69.3 ns
```

i.e. factor of about `1e5`! It is also pretty clear why: in order to check that the passed list is really of type `reflected list(array(float64, 1d, C))` numba has to look at every element in the list. On the other hand, for the `TypedList` it is much simpler: there cannot be no more than one type in the list - there is no need to iterate over the whole list!

Thus one should prefer to create and use `TypedList`s and not just to dismiss a [deprecation warning](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types).

---

It is probably not possible to give a string for `reflected list` or `TypedList`, because right now [the following code](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/13ece9b97e6f01f750e870347f231282325f60c3/numba/core/sigutils.py#L12) is used to parse the signature:

```
def _parse_signature_string(signature_str):
    # Just eval signature_str using the types submodules as globals
    return eval(signature_str, {}, types.__dict__)
```

and because `nb.types.__dict__` has no `TypedList` or `reflected list` we cannot pass them via string.

---

Once the functions are compiled (ahead-of-time or just-in-time) it is possible to see the signatures in the corresponding [`Dispatcher`-object](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html#dispatcher-objects), for example via:

```
[x.signature for x in fun.overloads.values()]
# [(ListType[array(float64, 1d, C)],) -> none,
#  (reflected list(array(float64, 2d, C)),) -> none]
```

This can be used to figure out the right return-type of the function (here `none` means  `void`).

Comment: I dont understand the decorator `@nb.jit([nb.void(nb.typeof(typed_list)),
         nb.void(nb.typeof(simple_list))])
def fun(lst):
    pass`
why is it a list in a tuple and why nb.void?

it seems like my initial idea for a pattern `@jit(type_of_returned_value(type_of_x, type_of_b))` is wrong

Comment: @La-Li-Lu-Le-Low I compile function for two different signatures (thus the list) ahead of time. Tried to explain better with an edit.

Comment: I understand it like this:
1.) Use numba Lists (speed inrcease, otherwise deprecation)
2.) `@nb.jit([nb.void(nb.typeof(typed_list)),
         nb.void(nb.typeof(simple_list))])` indeed is like `@jit(type_of_returned_value(type_of_x, type_of_b))` where `np.void` is the type of the function and `nb.typeof(simple_list)` is the type of the parameter. But youre not specifying any type of output, because its a `nb.void()`. 
3.) Also you are passing two possible compilation formats for the function (right?), therefore you put them both in a `[]`. Would it only be 
`@jit(...(...))` otherwise?

Comment: 4.) why is this correct: `@jit("void(int32, float32)")
            def foo(x, y):
                return x + y`  ? Its a void but it returns something...